# Setting Boolean in datasnapshot returns null after setting it to true

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean

here is my code:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String titleString, userID, uploadID, imageURL, userOnlineString;
private Boolean userOnlineBoolean;
private int imageRotation;
private TextView titleCustomBar, lastSeenCustomBar;
private ImageView imageCustomBar;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRefUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    //Log.e("Lol", userOnlineString);

    mDatabaseRefUser.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Online").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userOnlineBoolean = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            Log.e("lol ", ""+userOnlineBoolean);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    titleString = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE");
    userID = intent.getStringExtra("USERID");
    uploadID = intent.getStringExtra("UPLOADID");
    imageRotation = intent.getIntExtra("IMAGEROTATION", 0);
    imageURL = intent.getStringExtra("IMAGEURL");



    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customActionBar = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custombar, null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBar);

    titleCustomBar = findViewById(R.id.title_textview_id);
    lastSeenCustomBar = findViewById(R.id.last_seen_textview_id);
    imageCustomBar = findViewById(R.id.custom_image_id);

    titleCustomBar.setText(titleString);

    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Glide.with(this).load(imageURL)
            .into(imageCustomBar);
    imageCustomBar.setRotation(imageRotation);
   if(userOnlineBoolean){
       userOnlineString = "Online";
    }
    lastSeenCustomBar.setText(userOnlineString);



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
        finish();
    }
    else {
        mDatabaseRefUser.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Online").setValue(true);

    }
}
```

}

in the log, `userOnlineBoolean` is returning true. Further down, in the `if-statement` userOnlineBoolean is null, why is that?

I have tried many changes but nothing works. Why is it null after returning `true`.

I have tried solving this for hours, but I don't find the issue, or see the problem. If you know whats wrong with my code, feel free to share with you.

Comment: Just a quick guess, you print the variable in an anonymous listener which is typically executed in an asynchronous way. Might it be that code in the if-clause is called _before_ it is logged in the ``onDataChange`` method? Furthermore, you might see the logging output a lot later than it actually happened.

Comment: how do I solve this issue?

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not run the code, I suspect the issue is caused by the anonymous inner class.

Let's look at the execution of the method "onCreate":

You call the super, 
You make a couple of static calls. 
You add an event listener to an object (this is the anonymous inner class, this instance is created but the methods are not executed)
Then you assign some values
A couple more calls.
Then you "if" on the value which is only changed in the change listener.

At this point your boolean is not set.
So will throw a null pointer.

There are various ways to fix this, but hopefully be you understand the root cause.

Comment: so it means that my method onDataChange, isn't called until after the if statement. how do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue by doing this:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userOnlineBoolean = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if(userOnlineBoolean){
                userOnlineString = "Online";
                settextmethod();
            }

 private void settextmethod() {
    lastSeenCustomBar.setText(userOnlineString);
}
```

But I still don't understand why my previous way was wrong.

Comment: It's because your if statement was executing before your change listener. The change listener would not execute the code to set your Boolean until a later change event, which could be milliseconds, seconds, minutes, or even never.

Comment: What is your stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

An `EventListener` is typically called asynchronously. Your `if`-clause is probably being processed *before* the `onDataChange` callback is executed.

Find below a proposal to solve your issue.

First, you should reconsider the variable `userOnlineBoolean` itself. It is always a good idea to think about the states a variable could have during its lifetime. In this case, you could argue that there are only two states: a user is online or he is not. If so, you should avoid that variable to be *undefined* or *null*. Initialize your variable right away, i.e. when declaring it:

```
private boolean userOnlineBoolean = false;
```

As you can see, I used a `primitive boolean` instead of the wrapper class `Boolean` to make sure it can't be null.

Now, you've got a lot of code in the `onCreate()` method. I don't know about the context of you application, but that method is probably called only once. However, you want the relevant parts of your UI to be updated not only once but probably *everytime* your database changes. So the code should go into the `EventListener` or, better, into a separate method, that is called from within the `EventListener`.

Well, you might want to remove the following code from the onCreate() method:

```
if(userOnlineBoolean){
   userOnlineString = "Online";
}
lastSeenCustomBar.setText(userOnlineString);
```

and put it into a new method like this.

```
private void updateUIOnDatabaseChange() {
   userOnlineString = userOnlineBoolean ? "Online" : "";
   lastSeenCustomBar.setText(userOnlineString);
}
```

Note, that I've considered the case that the user's status changes from *online* to *not online*. That's why I replaced the `if` clause by a ternary operator (a short form for if-else).

And update your `onDataChange`, as well

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  userOnlineBoolean = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
  updateUIOnDatabaseChange();
  Log.e("lol ", ""+userOnlineBoolean);
}
```

I think that's a more practical and reasonable design. Let me know if this works for you.